# SharePoint 2007 Search Crawling Failed

Tags: search, crawling, service-account

I have problem in SharePoint 2007 Search Crawling in Index Server, it display error message in the Crawl Log stated "Could not Connect to the server. Please make sure the site is accessible" and no content able to be crawl.

The SharePoint farm is consists of one Web Server, one Index Server and one Database Server;  Index Server should be having the role of crawling content from Web Server.

Steps I had taken for troubleshooting:

- try access the site from Index Server (OK)
- make sure the content access account able to login into the site (OK)
- Windows SharePoint Services Search is not disable

any other step I can take for troubleshooting? thank you for your advises in advanced.

Comment: Are you using FQDN by any chance (e.g. instead of server name as http://myServerName you are using http://intranet or anything similar)? If so, you need to disable LoopBackCheck in Registry. I would have said to look for firewall settings, but since all runs on a single box, might not be the case

Comment: The error states that the content access account is not able to connect to the site. Try adding AAMs for the site in CA, with localhost and the ip address of the machine. Try accessing the site with all these local addresses. Also change the hosts file if necessary. Then reset and recrawl.

Comment: thanks Marius, I added LoopBackCheck in Registry before, guess it must be the one causing the crawling failed, after I removed it, the crawl working fine

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

One thing to remember is that crawling SharePoint sites is different from crawling file shares or non-SharePoint websites.

A few other quick pointers:

•the sps3: protocol is for crawling user profiles for People Search. You can disregard anything the crawler says about it until you're ready for user profiles.

•your crawl account is supposed to have access to your entire farm. If you see permissions errors, find the KB article that tells you the how to reset your crawl account (it's a specific stsadm.exe command). If you're trying to crawl another farm's content, then you'll have to work something else out to grant your crawl account access. I think this is your biggest issue presently.

•The crawler (running from the index server) will attempt to visit the public URL. I've had inter-server communication issues before; make sure all three servers can ping each other, and make sure the index server can reach the public URL (open IE on the index server and check it out). If you have problems, it's time to dirty up your index server's hosts file. This is something SharePoint does for you anyway, so don't feel too bad doing it. If you've set up anything aside from Integrated Windows Authentication, you'll have to work harder to get your crawler working.

above was taken from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101182/moss-2007-crawl

also have a look at these links:
http://davidnotions.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/got-error-could-not-connect-to-server.html

http://sharepointroot.com/2012/03/16/sharepoint-search-the-crawler-could-not-communicate-with-the-server/

Hope it helps :)